# Trying to retrieve data from database in Symfony fails

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database with the following code:

```
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $pm = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Privatemessage')
    ->findOneByUser_userid($user->getUserid());
```

Then in my twig file I use this:

```
        {% for i in 0..(pm|length-1)%}
            <tr>
                <td>{{pm[i].sender}}</td><td></td><td>{{pm[i].subject}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{pm[i].contents()}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

This fails however, and gives me the following error:

```
Impossible to access a key "0" on an object of class "Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Privatemessage" that does not implement ArrayAccess interface in LoginLoginBundle:Default:manager.html.twig at line 20
```

If I use findall(), everything works fine, but then I get all the objects and I just need a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to retrieve all private messages of a given user and display them. In that case you should use `findBy*()` instead of `findOneBy*()`. The former will return an `ArrayCollection` instead of just an instance of `PrivateMessage`.

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$pm = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Privatemessage')
    ->findByUser_userid($user->getUserid());
```

I also recommend using **Twig**'s `for` to iterate through each item of the collection like this:

```
{% for message in pm %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{message.sender}}</td><td></td><td>{{message.subject}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{message.contents()}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You can read the documentation [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html).

Comment: Hello, thanks for this, the for-loop is indeed better as the one that I was using. Everything works fine now :D

Answer (score 2):

`findOneBy()` methods are used to query only one instance of your object. It doesn't return a collection through which you can iterate.

In the code you shared you're fetching **only one** instance of `Privatemessage` and you're trying to manipulate it as if it was a collection of private messages. You **can't** do that.

Your code is working fine when you use `findAll()` because `findAll()` returns an [ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.2/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) of private messages which you can iterate through.

If you want to get **only some** of your private messages based on any given constraints, you've then to [apply filters](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods) when querying them.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, i have been searching how I can apply these filters, but didn't find anything.. how can i apply a filter to my query?

Comment: By using where(), orderBy() & setMaxResults(), ...etc [Here's the documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods). You've also to change the way you're iterating through your results, @FyodorX is right, You've to iterate through each item of your collection using {% for ... in ... %} loop